# Select one table cell and have multiple cells momentarily highlight

Tags: iphone

I have related items in adjacent table cells.  When either of the related items is selected, before going to the detail view, I would like the momentary cell selection highlight to show both (or in some cases 3) cells highlighted to alert the user of the relationshp.

This a purely a "nice to have" cosmetic feature.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I would wager that using highlighting for anything other than a transient indication of the exact cell a user has tapped could result in app rejection because of non-standard UI. Proceed at your own caution.

Answer (score 0):

In the method called when the user selects a row you can use:

```
[cell setSelected:YES];
```

One way to get the cell would be using tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method (correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0):

*** FOLLOW-UP TO Shaggy Frog ***

I appreciate your comments.

For some reason, I can't add a comment to or edit my own original question so I am editing my follow-up.

May I have an opinion on the following.  Since the 2 highlightd cells would always be adjacent and the data related, it makes sense that the detail view contain details for both cells.  However your point is valid and I don't want to get rejected.

Instead of 2 cells, if for the "related cells" I were to double the height of those cells, draw a horizontal line half way between (to make the 2 "subcells" of 44 pixels in height looking just like 2 cells) and place the data in subviews so the result looks exactly the same as 2 cells but it would actually be 1 cell.  Selection of one of my "subcells" would then highlight 2 "subcells" which is the entire cell - same effect but 1 cell.

Do you think that would pass?

And of course the biggest advantage is that I know how to do this versus the multi-cell highlighting which doesn't seem possible.